# Vue js и работа со скриптами

Tags: vue.js

Всем добрый день!
Работаю с vue.js и хотел уточнить. У меня такая структура файлов:

```
    views
     -index
     -about
     -todos
```

В каждом файле есть свои скрипты, которые задаются так:

```
<script>
 export default { ... }
</script>
```

Будут ли на главную страницу (index) подгружаться все скрипты одновременно? Или во vue уже подразумевается загрузка только скриптов главной страницы.

И если будут все скрипты подгружаться (по крайней мере при просмотре кода страницы они все подгружаются), то как это урегулировать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вью подразумевает деление на чанки на уровне роутов. [Вот тут](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html) можно почитать подробнее. Во всех остальных случаях вью делает единый бандл для всего приложения. Хотя ещё можно посмотреть в сторону отдельных чанков на уровне именно джаваскрипта и [вэбпака](https://webpack.js.org/guides/lazy-loading/). Но этот вариант предполагает использование чанков, как отдельных ресурсов именно внутри компонента. Пока не могу представить юзкейс для этого. Разделить компоненты на чанки средствами вью можно только на уровне роутов по первой ссылке.

Comment: Да, я вот тоже читал про чанки. Получается такая структура: component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "main-page" */ '@/views/index.vue'). Аналогично с другими страницами. Но все равно скрипты подгружаются ко всем трем страницам... Мб что-то не так делаю?

Comment: Или, разделяя на чанки, несмотря на то, что они видны при просмотре кода страница - подгружаются асинхронно при переходе на нужную страницу?